# How to access a variable from another method

Tags: java, android

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.barchartnew);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(8f, 0));
        return rootView;
    }

    public void test() {
        // Here I want to access bargroup1
    }
}
```

How can I access the array list variable `bargroup1` in `public void test()`?

I have tried inserting `ArrayList bargroup1;` below `public class Tab1 extends Fragment {` and deleting `ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();` but then my app crashes.

Comment: Your app crashed because you still need to *initialize* the variable, not just define it

Comment: How might I do that @cricket_007?

Comment: `private ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();` is not the same as just `private ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1;`

Comment: make ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1 global

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your  var as an instance variable , initialize it in the `onCreateView` method then you can use your var in other methods :

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


    HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.barchartnew);

    bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(8f, 0));
return rootView;
}

public void test(){

        // Here I want to access bargroup1

    }

}
```

Comment: This is more of a java question than strictly android. Scope can be block level like within an if statement, apply to just a method as in the original question here, member variable/class level such as you posted in the answer, global variables can be achieved by extending Application or you could access another project or by a URL. Test should really be done another way